# Unable to cancel NSTimer that executes blocks

Tags: ios, objective-c, button, timer, nstimer

I know that these `NSTimer` questions have come up numerous times, however since none seem to involve executing blocks that change the UI, I figured this is still an original question.

I have a subclass of `UIButton` that, for convenience sake (me, coming from an `Android` background), has an `onClick` and `onHoldClick` function. `onClick` simply takes a block and executes it in the selector that responds to `UIControlEventTouchUpInside`. The click function works great. For example:

```
[myButton setOnClick:^{
    NSLog(@"clicked");
}];
```

The hold click functionality is not working so well.

```
[myButton setOnHoldClick:^{
    NSLog(@"still holding click...");
}];
```

This listens for the `UIControlEventTouchDown` event, and performs a task after a delay:

```
- (void)clickDown:(id)sender
{
    isClicked = YES;

    [self performSelector:@selector(holdLoop:) withObject:nil afterDelay:delay];//For the sake of the example, delay is set to 0.5  
}
```

The hold loop runs a repeated timer on another function, which handles the block execution (the *timer* variable is an `NSTimer` declared in the header file):

```
-(void)holdLoop:(id)sender
{
    [self cancelTimers];
    _timer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:0.5 target:self selector:@selector(death:) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
}

-(void)death:(id)_delay
{

    if (isClicked)
    {
        _holdBlock();
    }
    else
    {
        [self cancelTimers];

    }
}
```

The block that executes changes the value of a float, which is used to update the value of a label, which is then redrawn.

The first time the hold click event occurs, this works great. After that, it seems like timers don't get canceled, and new timers are still added. This is what my `cancelTimers` function looks like (calls here are retrieved from a collection of the other questions on this topic):

```
-(void)cancelTimers
{
    [_timer invalidate];
    [NSObject cancelPreviousPerformRequestsWithTarget:self selector:@selector(death:) object:nil];
}
```

What am I doing wrong, and how do I fix it?

**Edit**

I do, in fact, already have the function that responds to touch up inside:

```
- (void)clickUp:(id)sender
{
    isClicked = NO;
    [self cancelTimers];
    _clickBlock();
}
```

Furthermore, I have realized that the issue comes from an unhandled cancel event. Is there a reason why iOS would auto-cancel my long press?

Comment: Do you want the timer to fire only one time? Or only to fire as long as the button is held down?

Comment: @MohannadA.Hassan, I only want it to fire when the button is being pressed. The `isClicked` BOOL value is meant to keep track of the clicked state.

Comment: So did you make sure that the `isClicked` is set to `NO` when it's supposed to.

Comment: Note that `UIGestureRecognizer` is a much more powerful and consistent way to approach this problem. It has specific handling for "long press."  Trying to build it out of the parts you are using will tend to lead to UI elements that do not behave like standard iOS elements unless you do a lot of extra work.

Answer (score 2):

**Solved**

Since the block redrew the UI, it was also redrawing the buttons (and resetting their functionality). This event was causing a cancel event to be called on the button - which was not handled. Adding the following:

```
[self addTarget:self action:@selector(cancelClick:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchCancel];
[self addTarget:self action:@selector(cancelClick:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpOutside];


-(void)cancelClick:(id)sender
{
    isClicked = NO;
    [self cancelTimers];
}
```

As well as reconsidering what changes are made in the block, has gotten me past this issue.

Answer (score 1):

As I understood from the comments and the code, the `clickDown:` is called for `UIControlEventTouchDown` so `isClicked` is set to `YES` when the first time the button is touched down. You need to add a selector to the event `UIControlEventTouchUpInside`. It's called when the user lifts his finger while being iside the bound of the button. Inside that method, set `isClicked` to `NO`.

Comment: I do have this event already registered. See the edit to my question.